# SQL Server as a Web Service Client

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, web-services, soap

Suppose given a URL, http://test.org/service.asmx

How can I use SOAP method in SQL Server to access the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [write managed code](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Introducing-SQL-Server-2005s-CLR-Integration/) (C# or VB.NET) and run it from SQLServer. And you can write a SOAP client with .NET, of course.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This should work too

```
Declare @Object as Int ;

Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000) ;

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT ;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
    'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
    'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select  @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

But I do think too that it is best to write a CLR function that you use from your sp

Answer (score 0):

I successfully created a Web Service (SQL Server 2005) using the above technique and it works great populating a list box in the InfoPath preview mode.  When I publish the form to SharePoint, only the first row populates the list box rather than the entire record set.  good article, i really like it.  I am doing a bit on research about web service directly and i found also macrotesting www.macrotesting.com to be very good source.  Thanks for you article.....

Regards...

Meganathan..